# apploading splashscreen with hooks

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-hooks

How do you achieve loading resources while showing the splash screen when you are using functional components with hooks?  What is the pattern in using apploading and/or splashscreen with hooks?

Thanks!

Bill

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: In the expo documentation, they recommended using the apploading component.  The example they gave is using class based component (please see https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/).  How do I use this with react hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only understand **Hook's** `useState`, this is a very easy change. This is simply converted into a function, and the state value is resolved using `hooks`. If you change the example of `AppLoading` to `Hook`, the code below is as follows.

**AppLoading use Hooks**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View ,Image } from "react-native";
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';

export default function App() {
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);

  const  _cacheResourcesAsync = async () => {
    const images = [require('./assets/snack-icon.png')];

    const cacheImages = images.map(image => {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }); 
    return Promise.all(cacheImages);
  }

  return (
     isReady === false ? ( <AppLoading
      startAsync={_cacheResourcesAsync}
      onFinish={() => setReady(true)}
      onError={console.warn}
    />) : (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Image source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} />
    </View>)
  );
}
```